# If $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n=1$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=1$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ be two sequences in $\mathbb R$. Let $n_k=2^k-2$ and $b_k=\sum_{n=n_k+1}^{n_{k+1}}a_n$ for each $k\in \mathbb N$. If $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_n=1$, then does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=1$ hold?

Intuitively, I guess it holds, but I don't know how to prove.

What I know is that if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges, then the value of convergence must be 1, so it would be sufficient to prove only the convergence.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: It doesn't hold. Between $n_k$ and $n_{k+1}$ there is a lot of room to get huge partial sums, and then go back. Play with $a_n = \pm \frac{1}{k}$ for $n_k < n \leqslant n_{k+1}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer That counterexample doesn't work since $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n $ also converges.

Comment: Not if you do it right. The sequence of partial sums of a convergent series is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: @DanielFischer Oh that's right. Thanks!